# Two colored date in onezone datepicker

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, datepicker

I'm using ionic onezone datepicker for the representation of calendar in my app,but for certain date I need to provide two colored date as show below.Can anyone help me with that.
[image]

Comment: Need more information. Post your code what you have tried.

Comment: i have just added the plugin script and few lines of code have a look at it.

Comment: this is in controller

Comment: $scope.onezoneDatepicker = {
        date: new Date(), // MANDATORY
        mondayFirst: false,
        disablePastDays: false,
        disableSwipe: false,
        disableWeekend: false,
        showDatepicker: false,
        showTodayButton: true,
        calendarMode: true,
        hideCancelButton: true,
        hideSetButton: false,
        highlights: [
          {
          date: new Date(2016, 6, 6),
          color: '#8FD4D9',
          textColor: '#f00',

        }],
        callback: function(value) {
            // return;
        }

    };

Comment: and this is in view

Comment: <ion-list>
                <onezone-datepicker datepicker-object="onezoneDatepicker">

                </onezone-datepicker>
            </ion-list>

Comment: sorry for the format